# Repetition in piece-wise function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

In my pre-calculus course lesson, I have this word problem:

> Amy's electric bill can be represented by the piecewise function:
>   $$\begin{cases}
> 8.25+0.0705x, &x≤400 \\  
> 36.45+0.0605x, &x>400
> \end{cases}$$
>
> where $x$ is the number of kilowatt hours used. Use this function to determine the cost of her electric bill if she used $825$ kilowatt hours. Round your answer to the nearest cent.

If I calculate the first line, "Amy's" bill is $\$36.45$ for the first 35 hours, as we see.
In the *second* line, It takes 36.45 and adds it to the reduced rate, right? Makes sense, **except**, that the $0.0605x$ rate is applied to the entire bill of 825 hours, ***not*** just the remaining 425 hours?

Why does the piece-wise function apply the reduced rate to the *entire* bill instead of just the remaining hours? Does this mean that I'm getting billed twice for some of my hours from my electric company (assuming this is a real-world accurate function)? :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that this is a very strange function. The cost for $400$ kilowatt hours is $\$36.45$, while the cost for $401$ kilowatt hours is $\$60.71$.

Probably the author intended to write a function that does the following:

- $\$8.25$ service charge
- $\$0.0705$ per hour for the first $400$ kilowatt hours
- $\$0.0605$ per hour for kilowatt hours beyond $400$

The first piece of the function is correct, and the slope of the second piece is correct. As you point out, however, you are being charged again for the first $400$ kilowatt hours, which we need to subtract off somehow.

We could fix this error by solving
$$
b + 0.0605 \cdot 400 = 36.45,
$$
since any reasonable function should give us the same cost at $400$ hours in both pieces. We get $b = 12.25$, which means the second piece of the function should have been
$$
12.25 + 0.0605x \text{ if } x > 400.
$$

Comment: Hence why I was confused - I got the problem wrong in the lesson, because I didn't think one would be billed twice for 400 hours. Thanks for the thoughts!